# Nightwatch unable to access the element of iframe

Tags: javascript, selenium, dom, iframe, nightwatch.js

I am using xquery selector and I tried to set value of the input field in the iframe but all in vain.

```
   `.frame('someid')
    .setValue('//input[contains(@name,"project name")]', 'Nightwatch Project')
    .pause(5000)
    .frame(null)`
```

It says unable to locate element: "//input[contains(@name,"project name")]" using: xpath

Comment: did you switch to the iframe first before setting value to an input field within iframe?

Comment: First I go to the application and click a button from which a kind of pop up form appears. There I want to fill the info. Back to your question, I directly went to frame by using .frame('someid'). Before that I haven't done anything related to frame. So, I switched to frame first and then changed the input field.

Comment: Well i'm sure on the xquery selector, but i can see .frame('someid') will yield the same results as switch_to.frame in python bindings. Since the form opens in a popup, it may be a new window, in which case you may need to swich to that new window and then setValue

Comment: So, how should I switch tot he new window. In my local host, it has the same address as the previous window. The new window remains in the old window by overlaying old one.

Comment: if its an overlay, its most likely not a new window, can you update your post with the html

Answer (score 0):

Not possible because of security concern. The alternative is You can set value using the JavaScript postmessage event api . Whenever you want to set value in iframe you will send postmessage event from outer window and listen it on inner window  and set value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage